# Win Server 2008 + Virtualization, A Beginners question

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I want to start my first virtualized work environment and i don't know what is better to do.

I have windows 2008 R2 Std edition.

i want to setup 2 HyperV machines

Do i first setup the windows server on the HW or do i better install the HyperV Core on the HW ?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Versions_and_variants

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, Hyper-V allows you to install the Hyper-V host and a single virtualised server instance using the single license (Server 08 comes with both physical and virtual license keys for this). Unless you have purchased a separate license for the Hyper-V host as well as the two VMs, you're not allowed to use the Hyper-V host for anything other than Hyper-V.

So, run up the host, then create both Hyper-V child servers. It will give you much greater flexibility in any case.

Comment: I am in a need of an application and a database server. So i am considering of buying two 2008 R2 Licenses. In 3 months i'm gonna launch a terminal server for remote branches. Do i have to buy a 3rd license ?

Comment: @cmosk - buy 1 enterprise license then, because you're then entitled to 4 virtual instances.

Answer (score 1):

You install Hyper-V server on the bare metal and then you install 2008 as a guest inside it.

Comment: Buy installing the 2008R2 as a guest do i still have the option of the 2nd HyperV guest license ?

Comment: What do you mean by hyper-v guest license? Hyper-v server is free. Install that on the bare metal. Then install whatever guests you have licenses for. If you buy enterprise edition you got 4 guests.

Comment: I have to say that I think telling him to install Hyper-V Server (which has no friendly user interface other than a command line) is probably a disservice to him, given his level of newness to the topic.  Hyper-V server is more appropriate for people who are completely comfortable with the concepts and who know Windows inside and out, to the point that scripts are second nature.

Comment: Hyper-V is hardly command line only. There's a Hyper-V management console that's also free.

Comment: so it is mostly recomended for me to setup the r2 and enable the HyperV role of the server instead of installing HyperV Core?

Comment: @MarkM; I have to agree with Jake. If this guy had someone close by to walk him through Hyper-V I'd go straight for Hyper-V Server. That lacking I'd remind him not to use hid learning box for production and to start with a Full install of Standard. All the management tools for Hyper-V Server work on a Standard Full (except the one CLI tool) so he can get the hang of remote management.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion going around about the various forms that HyperV can take. There are a number of different ways to use it, but the easiest for you will be to simply enable the HyperV role within Server 2008 R2. Don't worry about doing anything else.

Set up the r2 server on the physical box, and enable the HyperV role on it. Just don't install anything else on the physical box.

As for your licensing, hopefully this will clarify:

Hopefully this will help clarify:

Server 2008 R2 license 1: 
1. Install on the physical hardware using the Physical install key.
2. Install in the first HyperV child you run up using the Virtual install key.

Under Microsoft's EULA, you can use the same license for both the physical box and the first VM as long as all the physical box is doing is running the Hyper-V management console. If you want it to do more than run HyperV, then you'll need to purchase a separate license for the physical install.

If you want to run up additional servers after the first, you'll need to purchase additional licenses. If you purchase Server 2008 R2 standard, you'll need one license per VM. If you purchase Server 2008 R2 enterprise, then as stated above, you can run up to 4 VMs.

Mark, by HyperV guest license, I assume Cmosk is talking about the Virtual installation license as opposed to the Physical installation license.

**On a side note, be careful running a TS on a virtual system. Make sure you've got appropriate hardware to support it. In my experience, disk I/O can bottleneck really badly on a virtual TS if you're not careful.**

Answer (score 0):

If you will use this machines only to virtualization you should use a core edition, this is because it has a smaller footpring and cosumes less hardware resources in the parent partition. You can manage them from a client PC using Hyper-V remote magamente console.

If you have only Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard maybe is not  a good idea to use them in ths scenario. There is a Windows Server 2008 Core Edition enable only to run Hyper-V, is Call [Hyper-V Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/hyper-v-server/default.aspx) and is completly free, included support.

If you have Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise edition is better because you can make a cluster between both host machines.